# Delphi 10.x "Cannot resolve unit name" for newly installed library

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, delphi-10.3-rio

I encountered the following puzzling situation while installing a third-party library, in this case Virtual Treeview, which I will use as an example herein.

After following the installation procedure from INSTALL.txt, the new components appeared in Delphi's component palette, and can be added to a form.

However, building one of the supplied example projects, in this case "Minimal" fails, saying:

'Cannot resolve unit name "VirtualTrees" at line xxx', which is the uses statement in which VirtualTrees is listed.

Congruent with that symptom, in the source code editor, (uses) VirtualTrees, and subsidiary component declarations, were marked with red squiggles, indicating identifier undeclared or not resolved.

The supplied demo project was set to target Windows 32.  But puzzlingly, if I switch the target to Windows 64, it will compile.

Installation consisted of:

1. Unzip the supplied zip file to wherever you locate source packages.
2. In Delphi, open the project group: File > Open ....  VirtualTreeView.groupproj
3. Once loaded, in the project tree, right click on VirtualTreesD26.bpl > Install.
4. Add VirtualTreeView's "Source" folder to the Library Path, using 
   "Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Library > Library Path > [...]"

What's allowing the IDE to know about the component, but then failure to compile for Windows 32, yet success for Windows 64?

Comment: Your resolution should be posted as an answer, not added to the question. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It's inappropriate to edit it into the question itself.

Comment: @KenWhite I acknowledge that judging by rep you do much to benefit the community. In this case I ask what's wrong with putting explanatory and resolution material in the question narrative? I explicitly accepted another answer, and don't want to undo that. If I were to add an additional answer, whatever I put there would be skipped by readers thinking it's not "The" answer. That goal here is to inform people, not to preserve a precise sequence of who said what when.

Comment: @KenWhite Also "Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question at any time." Which doesn't say you have to add the additional material as an answer post, and even suggests you can "add the answer to the question".

Comment: No, *add an answer* means *add an answer*, which is done in the space below where there is a text area with the heading **Your Answer** above it.  I can roll back your edit, but I was offering you the opportunity to get the text yourself so you didn't have to do as much work. It's not a debate; answers belong in the answer section,  questions belong in the question. They're two different things, and are kept that way for a reason. Your edit can still be rolled back, but (again) I'm offering you the opportunity to do so yourself first.

Comment: You don't have to undo accepting another answer to add one of your own as well. You can  leave David's answer as the accepted one, upvote it if you'd like, and still post your own answer. There is no requirement  that you not accept someone else's answer when you post your own.

Comment: I would say your interpretation of "Can I answer my own" is overly strict. It does not say answer material may only be in the Answer section.  If it did you'd have to ban people from posting answer material in the comments attached to the question, like here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402040/delphi-use-case-on-advbadgeglowbutton1-caption

Comment: No, it says that answers should be posted as an answer, which is in the space below. You can choose to comment as much as you like, within the guidelines, but comments do not affect the division between question and answer. I don't know why you're being so obstinate about simply adhering to the site's design intent and guidelines, but you're free to open a discussion at [meta] about revamping the site design if you'd like. Until you do so and that suggestion is accepted and implemented, you're expected to adhere to the current one.

Comment: "Obstinate": I already complied with your request.  "it says that answers should be posted as an answer". Actually it does not say that. It says that adding an answer  to your own question post is _permitted_ and _encouraged_, to specifically rebut those who thought own answers were against some rule. Maybe your rule is spelled out somewhere, but not there. "No, _add an answer_ means _add an answer_": you infer "answer" means only "answer post", yet in "add an answer to your own question" interpret "question" cannot mean "question post". Regardless, does not prohibit it.

Comment: @KenWhite You now appear to have reverted back my edit 3, which complied with your edit request, back to my very original post, which is the worst version of all, as I have explained. Please let me know what your rationale is for that.

Comment: ... and I have now again replaced the initial question to remove distracting issues that turned out not to relate to the core problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each target has its own library path. You have added the VT paths to the Win64 target, but need to do the same for the Win32 target.

Alternatively, remove the VT paths from the Win64 target search path, and add them instead to the target that applies to all projects, and then they will be inherited by the other projects.

In the options dialog there is a drop down control that allows you to specify the target to which your settings are to be applied.

Comment: To be clear, for others, on Delphi's Tool > Options ... > Library settings there's a Platform dropdown which governs which platform the below settings will apply to. Apparently it defaulted to Win64 in a new Delphi install. In addition, the individual project has settings via Project Tree > Build Configuration by which to override the global paths, for individual platforms, or all platforms.  OK, I think I understand this better now.

Comment: @gwideman When the screen is first opened, it defaults to whichever platform your project is currently switched to.

Comment: @Jerry I'm not convinced that is correct. I saw this very issue happen yesterday at the spring4d conf.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan On further study, I believe where your answer says "target that applies to all _projects_", you're probably referring to the project-level settings that pertain to all _Build Configurations_? Ie: Here, in the project tree, ProjectGroup1 > Minimal.exe > Build Configurations > Right-click > (Project options dialog) Building > Delphi Compiler > Target (All configurations, or particular target) > Search path slot.   And side note here: Delphi apparently merges "Search path" with Tools > ... > Library settings > Library path, but not sure the rules.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the Library Path was not set correctly.  And credit to David Heffernan for pointing that out.

But how and why?

The key piece that I missed was that the Library Settings dialog captures different sets of paths applicable to each of the different platform targets. So at the top of the Library Settings dialog there's a "Selected Platform" dropdown that governs which platform the settings beneath will be applied to.

To be able to build a Win 32 VCL application, the Library Path needs to be set specifically for Windows 32, which means setting the Selected Platform dropdown to Windows 32 before performing the step of adding the path to Virtual TreeView's Source directory.

Obvious in retrospect, and perhaps this SO post will help connect "Cannot resolve unit name" to this potential cause.

There are a couple of gotchas to add regarding why this happens.

a) Users coming from older versions of Delphi may be familiar with this Library Settings dialog before it handled multiple platforms, thus not realize that it now has a "Selected Platform" feature.

b) On my installation of Delphi 10.3, which is a fresh one, that "Selected Platform" dropdown reverts to Windows 64 every time you open the Library Settings dialog. It neither coordinates with the platform of the currently open project, nor does it remember what you last set it to, it seems. So it's easy to miss that it's not set to the platform you assumed, unless you know to look explicitly.

It may also be useful to know that while this functionality sets the library path for the entire Delphi installation ("globally"), there are overlapping settings at the project level, accessed as follows (for the example "Minimal" project):

Project tree, ProjectGroup1 > Minimal.exe > Build Configurations > Right-click > (Project options dialog) Building > Delphi Compiler > Target (All configurations, or particular target) > "Search path" slot.

Delphi apparently merges "Search path" with Tools > ... > Library settings > Library path.

Finally, for Virtual Treeview, its maintainer Joachim Marder has added a note to the installation instuctions to avoid the pitfall described here.